# biphasic Pulse Characterization

Tags: python

I've been searching for a few days for a simple c/c++ or python library that will help me gather parameters from a pulse similar to the one in the image below. I will be getting the data from an NI PXI oscope or digitizer and am looking for a library to help me out with the processing. I did discover that MathWorks has [something](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/examples/measurement-of-pulse-and-transition-characteristics.html) that would work, but i'm looking for something more c++ or python. Anyone know if this exists?

[image]